# Insights about W0rd2Vec

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text-mining, word-embeddings, transformer

As per my knowledge, Word2Vec is belongs to non-contextual embedding technique. this have only semantic relationship between words.

We can implement Word2Vec, either in CBoW or skip-gram model. but i confused with below statements:

1. The CBOW model is designed to predict a target word based on its surrounding context words.
2. Unlike the Skip-gram model, which predicts context words given a target word, CBOW focuses on predicting the target word itself.

since word2vec is non-contextual. but in CBoW, it is considering the context to find the target.
can you please give more insights about these two(CBoW, skip-gram).

Comment: The difference between contextual and non-contextual embeddings is to use or not the context **at inference time**. Neither CBoW nor skipgram word embeddings use the context at inference time, while BERT and RoBERTa do.

Comment: can you please give more details

Comment: Please describe specific doubts about what I said. For full info about those methods, there are dozens of online tutorials about word2vec (e.g. [original article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.3781), [tf tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/word2vec)) and also about BERT (e.g. [original article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.04805), [illustrated BERT](https://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/)).